# Multiple search and results in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im not sure if is possible but this is what i'm looking for with this data:

```
   id     |     name         |           email       |    address       | 
------------------+------------------------------------------------------
     1    | Jhon A           | jhon@test.com         |  st jhon 33      |
     2    | Jhonathan        | other@test.com        |  other address.  |  
     3    | Will             | will@test.com         |  miami           |
     4    | David            | davis@test.com        |  st jhon 33      |
```

need a single query to search some like "jhon" and results like:

```
{name: [{record_with_id_1, record_with_id_2}], email: [{record_with_id_1}], address: [{record_with_id_4}] }
```

I know I can do that querys separately but I need to do this and get separate results for about 6 different columns, so I want to know if it is possible to do it in a single query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you could aggregate each column separately.  I'm not sure what format you want for the actual results so I'll use arrays:

```
select array_agg(id) filter (where name ilike '%jhon%') as matching_names,
       array_agg(id) filter (where email ilike '%jhon%') as matching_emails,
       array_agg(id) filter (where address ilike '%jhon%') as matching_addresses
from t;
```